# Accessing a list of pages on your domain liked and how often?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbml, fbconnect

Is there a way of accessing what pages on your domain/site have been liked, and how often? Eg if I have a page on dogs, and one for each breed, I'd love to know which are the most popular liked. I looked into the JS SDK but it doesn't really seem to list a way. Facebook insights just provides the # of likes, but no actual breakdown (or export for that matter).

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877919/