# Most liked pages on a domain using graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, statistics, dns, facebook-like, facebook-insights

In the insights section on facebook, it's possible to have statistics of the most liked pages on the domain I own.
The question is, is it possible to obtain this list (on a website, not facebook pages) with the graph API, or at least, is it possible to obtain statistics which combines page url and likes count on a given domain ?
I read most of the facebook api doc and it seems that nothing like that exists.
Thanks!

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877919/