# Issue with getting Facebook pages like count in my account

Tags: facebook-fql

**Requirement**: Get like count of all pages under my FB account.

**FQL**  https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+user_id,object_id,post_id+FROM+like+WHERE+user_id=me()

**Problem** Every time i hit this FQL, i get the following ERROR:
"Querying like on user_id requires the read_stream extended permission."

**Source**
[Get Facebook "Like" count for every page on my domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877919/get-facebook-like-count-for-every-page-on-my-domain)

Please help me to solve this issue.

Best Regards,
Mohit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `read_stream` [extended permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/).

Grant this to your app and that query should work fine.

Comment: I have granted the read_stream permission to my application.

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/a8ayu.jpg

But still i am getting the same problem.

Comment: Does your access token actually have that permission? a call to /me/permissions will show you

Comment: just checked, dont have proper access https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=AAAB7Ud2Roq0BAONwpTGuh91g6gn2kGeeRfWWNQuc8fjM4k3ftHwavRpKRmGOTBbAvn2YsPCbaOK8Q0ZCkznLlCdw5HaLngIIsTJbeFlEb7H4PFOgu

Comment: can you please help me to provide necessary permissions, i am very new to this API and struggling since morning

Comment: remove the app from your account in your privacy settings and go back to it, it should ask for the new permission (i'm assuming you have authenticated referrals enabled)

Comment: Authenticated referrals is enabled in my app. but every time i remove and try access of application, i do not get any access dialog, rather i get this screen.   [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4pJ21.jpg

Comment: I am facing another issue which i have posted here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079509/fql-return-0-as-like-count-for-few-pages  It will be great if you can help me