# FQL return 0 as like count for few pages

Tags: facebook-fql

While running FQL query for retrieving page like count, i get 0 count for few pages. For most pages count comes fine but for few its always 0

**Steps to reproduce:**

Hit the following query:

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+url,normalized_url,share_count,like_count,comment_count,total_count,commentsbox_count,comments_fbid,click_count+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url+IN+(select+page_url+from+page+where+page_id+in+(344556287396,127535033990841,77277900503,293373084463))+

**Expected Behavior**
Correct like count should be returned:
http: //www.facebook.com/heyne.verlag (16,546)
http: //www.facebook.com/nwbVerlag (3,422)

**Actual Behavior:**
0 count is returned

I have checked with 150 pages, and find that FQL return 0 like count for 50+ pages. Please help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was by design. I was querying links of pages that are on Facebook.

link_stat reflects the interaction of users with a website, e.g. example.com. I made to query the page table in order to get the like count and was able to get correct count