# Facebook - get list of pages/links ever liked on my domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I create dynamic Facebook like-buttons for each of my article page on my website + anybody can do it with other pages.

I would like to know **how do I get a list of pages ever liked on my domain**?

Is it possible through Facebook Graph API ? If not is it even possible in FQL (since there is no wildcard)?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877919/get-facebook-like-count-for-every-page-on-my-domain) is trying to resolve similar problem, but the best solution from there is still counting on having a list of pages that you send to query, however I need a list of pages EVER liked on my domain meaning I also need to retrieve the "like-count" for already deleted pages (which I dont have a link to anymore).